# javascript radio button return previous checked value

Tags: javascript, radio-button

So I have this javascript code below. I am trying to make it so whenever the user hits cancel on the confirmation box. The previous selected option they have selected becomes reselected. Another option instead of the previous, is if we could have it select option 2 based on value ' A' instead of my current way of selecting option 2 based on the array of radio names.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmUnschedule() {
    var checked = false;
    var element = "";
    var inputs = document.getElementsByName('Acceptance');
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
          if (inputs[i].checked) {
           checked = true;
           element = inputs[i];
           break;
          }
        }   
    if(checked==true){
        if (!confirm('Scheduling will be undone if you change the rating. Are you Sure?')){
          inputs[1].checked=true;
        };
    };
   }
</script>

<input type='radio' name='Acceptance' value=' ' checked='checked' onclick='confirmUnschedule()'>option 1
<br/>
<input type='radio' name='Acceptance' value=' A' onclick='confirmUnschedule()'>option 2
<br/>
<input type='radio' name='Acceptance' value=' R' onclick='confirmUnschedule()'>option 3
<br/>
```

Comment: Can you put up a JSFiddle with HTML so we can can a better picture of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let your function return false, the event is aborted and the radio button group returns to previous state.

Edit: use return in the onclick attribute as well.

Html

```
<input type='radio' name='Acceptance' value=' ' checked='checked' onclick='return confirmUnschedule();'>option 1
<br/>
<input type='radio' name='Acceptance' value=' A' onclick='return confirmUnschedule();'>option 2
<br/>
<input type='radio' name='Acceptance' value=' R' onclick='return confirmUnschedule();'>option 3
<br/>
```

Javascript

```
function confirmUnschedule() {

    var checked = false;
    var element = "";
    var inputs = document.getElementsByName('Acceptance');

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].checked) {
            checked = true;
            element = inputs[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (checked === true) {
        if (!confirm('Scheduling will be undone if you change the rating. Are you Sure?')) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

jsFiddle  = http://jsfiddle.net/ahsjoe0x/

Comment: Its not selecting the previous option for me. It stays selected to whatever new option I select.

Comment: Se my updates, you can try it out with the jsFiddle link at the bottom.